# how do I redirect a url with array parameter in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect 
searchresults.php?categoryarray[]=Accessories 
to 
search-works.php?category=Accessories

```
rewrite ^/searchresults\.php(.*)$ /search-works.php?category=$arg_categoryarray[]? redirect;
```

The array in the old site url isn't really used so can assume a single 'category'.
My redirect is resulting in just "[]" as the category, and if I remove the brackets from the rewrite, then I get nothing from $arg_categoryarray.

Comment: So it seems it not possible without patching nginx source code `https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,241016` or you will need lua+nginx

Comment: Wow, not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you.
It's probably not worth the hassle of patching just for this rare instance.

Comment: Then simplest solution would be to to create that php filer and do the redirect inside the php code itself. It would just be a 2-3 liner code. So that is a better thing to do

Comment: well duh, that's brilliant [and so simple], thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tarun's comments solved this.
I went with creating a matching php file to do the redirect.